# Getting the "undefined reference to class::function" error on my C++ game.

Tags: c++, class, reference, undefined, member-functions

I am programming this game for a university work and i believe that my code is right, but i keep getting this error and it is keeping me from finishing my work in time. So here's the game board class header:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

class CMagicAlchemistBoard
{
public:

CMagicAlchemistBoard(void); //  Default Constructor
CMagicAlchemistBoard(const CMagicAlchemistBoard& board); //  Copy Constructor 
~CMagicAlchemistBoard(void ); //  Destructor
void SetupBoard(void);  // Function to setup the board
int GetBoardSpace(int row, int col); // Get the color at row,col

//  Accessor functions to get/set board size information 
int GetColumns(void) const { return m_nColumns; }
void SetColumns(int nColumns)  { m_nColumns = (nColumns >= 6) ? nColumns : 6; }
int GetRows(void) const { return m_nRows; }
void SetRows(int nRows)  { m_nRows = (nRows >= 8) ? nRows : 8; }

void DeleteBoard(void); //  Function to delete the board and free memory
void ExecuteMove(int row, int col);
bool IsGameOver(void) const;  //  Is the game over?
void DrawBoard(void);
bool ValidMove(int row, int col); // Function to see if a move is valid

private:

void CreateBoard(void); //Function to create the board and allocate memory
// Class Data
int** m_arrBoard; // 2D array pointer
//  Board size information
char m_arrChars[10];
int m_nColumns;
int m_nRows;        
};
```

And here is  the .cpp file with only the implementation of the DrawBoard() function:

```
#include "cmagicalchemistboard.h"
using namespace std;
void CMagicAlchemistBoard::DrawBoard(void)
{
cout << "MAGIC ALCHEMIST" << endl;
cout << "  ";
for(int col = 0; col < m_nColumns; col++){ printf(" ---",col); }
cout << endl;
for(int row = 0; row < m_nRows; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < m_nColumns; col++)
    {
        cout << "|  " << m_arrChars[GetBoardSpace(row, col)];
    }
    cout << "| " << endl; 
} 
}
```

I pretend to use this function on another class. Here's the header of that class:

```
#include "cmagicalchemistboard.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h> //Contains the function getch(), which reads the input from the     keyboard
#define LEFT_ARROW  75
#define RIGHT_ARROW  77
#define UP_ARROW 72
#define DOWN_ARROW 80
#define ESC 27

class CMagicAlchemist
{
public:
    CMagicAlchemist();
    ~CMagicAlchemist();
     // Functions for accessing the game board
    char GetBoardSpace(int row, int col) { return m_board->GetBoardSpace(row,     col); }
    void SetupBoard(void)         { m_board->SetupBoard(); }
    int GetColumns(void)          { return m_board->GetColumns(); }
    void SetColumns(int nColumns) { m_board->SetColumns(nColumns); }
    int GetRows(void)             { return m_board->GetRows(); }
    void SetRows(int nRows)       { m_board->SetRows(nRows); }
    void DeleteBoard(void)        { m_board->DeleteBoard(); }
    bool IsGameOver()             { return m_board->IsGameOver(); }
    void InputGameParameters();
    void GetMove(int &row, int &col);
    void DrawBoard();
    void NewGame();
    void Game();


private:
    CMagicAlchemistBoard* m_board; // Instance of the game board
    int m_nmoves;
};
```

And finally, the .cpp file of this last class with only the implementation of the function that calls the DrawBoard() function:

```
#include "cmagicalchemist.h"
void CMagicAlchemist::Game()
{
int x,y;
InputGameParameters();
NewGame();
DrawBoard();
}
```

So, my problem is: when i compile this program im getting this error: "undefined reference to CMagicAlchemist::DrawBoard()". This is stupid because the DrawBoard() function doesnt even belong to CMagicAlchemist class but instead, it belong to CMagicAlchemistBoard class. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Umm, there's a `DrawBoard` function right there in `CMagicAlchemist` and you're using it in the `Game` function as such.

Comment: yeah i thought that was the possible error too, but if i delete it from the CMagicAlchemist header i keep getting that error...

Answer (score 1):

You have DrawBoard *declared* in your CMagicAlchemist class.
You call DrawBoard from a CMagicAlchemist member function.

That tries to call Drawboard for the CMagicAlchemist class.

Comment: Technicality: if it was *defined*, this error wouldn't happen.

Comment: i deleted the Drawboard() function from the CMagicAlchemist header file and it still gives me that error. The thing is, we are supposed to base ourselves on an example that our teacher gave us and he makes it this way, and it works...

Comment: You need to change how you call DrawBoard. YOu need something like { CMagicAlchemistBoard board ; board.DrawBoard () ; }